# SupportSqliteQueryBuilder giving a wrong query results

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I am trying to create the following Query using `SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder` :

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE favorite=1 ORDER BY col1
```

I used the following code to build this query:

```java
public static SupportSQLiteQuery getSortedQuery(String sortByColname, boolean fav){
    SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder builder=
            SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder
                    .builder(DbUtils.Names.TABLE_NAME)
                    .columns(new String[]{Names.COL1,Names.COL2,Names.COL3,Names.COL4,Names.COL5,Names.COL_FAVORITE})
                    .orderBy(sortByColname) ;
    if(fav){
        builder.selection(Names.COL_FAVORITE,new String[]{"1"}  );
    }

    SupportSQLiteQuery query= builder.create();
    //Log.e("DB_UTILS", "getSortedQuery:query="+query.getSql());
    return  query;
}
```

But on checking the unit test , i found that following is the sql query that this method is generating :

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,col5 favorite  FROM tablename WHERE favorite ORDER BY col1
```

1. Why The arguement is not getting passed into this statement? why only `favourite` got generated and `favourite=1` ?
2. Is There a way to generate `*` in the query? writing all the colnames instead of `*` is painful

Comment: `selection` should take something like `someColumn = ?`, and yes, you can pass `*` to `columns` method

Comment: 1. Try replacing `Names.COL_FAVORITE` with `Names.COL_FAVORITE = ?`. 2. Try replacing `.columns(new String[]{Names.COL1,Names.COL2,Names.COL3,Names.COL4,Names.COL5,Names.COL_FAVORITE})` with `.columns(new String[]{"*"})`

Comment: @CommonsWare 2nd part was right but replacing `COL_FAVOURITE` with `COL_FAVOURITE + " = ?"` gave the following result `SELECT *  FROM tea WHERE favorite = ? ORDER BY name`

Comment: and whats wrong with your query: `"SELECT * FROM tea WHERE favorite = ? ORDER BY name"`?

Comment: @pskink `favourite =1` should be in the desired resultant query . i am trying to query for all results where a boolean `favourite` is true

Comment: each time you have `?` in your selection it will be replaced with the corresponding parameter taken from `String[]` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, I would use a raw query for this, with different SQL strings based on `fav`. But, if you really want to use `SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder`...

With regards to item 1, typically positional parameters are evaluated at runtime, which is what the `SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder` API is geared towards. So, you could:

- Replace `Names.COL_FAVORITE` with `Names.COL_FAVORITE = ?`, which will then use your `new String[]{"1"}` at runtime
- Replace `Names.COL_FAVORITE` with `Names.COL_FAVORITE = 1`, which will ignore your `new String[]{"1"}` at runtime

With regards to item 2, replace `.columns(new String[]{Names.COL1,Names.COL2,Names.COL3,Names.COL4,Names.COL5,Names.COL_FAVORITE})` with `.columns(new String[]{"*"})`.

Comment: ohh the runtime, i didn't considered that. probably that's why my test showed `?` because i was running this function on the jdk using Junit4 test. Thanks for the explanation. Although, is there a way to like, look at the arguments being passed? i see `query.getArgCount()` function , but not `query.getArgs()`

Comment: Hey @anshsachdeva How to try the accepted answer  I tried by doing queryBuilder.selection(DataTeaNames.COL_FAVORITE+"= ?", new String[]{"1"}); but didn't worked. do you know how to make this method work: public SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder selection(String selection, Object[] bindArgs) {
        mSelection = selection;
        mBindArgs = bindArgs;
        return this;
    }