# Issue with SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder's SELECTION method - Room Raw Query

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am trying to generate a RawQuery using SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder and it worked well but when I tried adding the **selection** method for generating a WHERE condition it just doesn't work.

Referred the docs from here: [https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder#selection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object[])](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/sqlite/db/SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder#selection(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) and found out that the method takes in two arguments.

1. The column name (for the WHERE condition)
2. The value

Tried it but somehow, the **second argument i.e bindArgs array is not added to the query**

The query I want:

> SELECT * FROM plants WHERE plantOrigin = "Japan"

The query being generated:

> SELECT  *  FROM plants WHERE plantOrigin

Tried this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56780629/8442557 but still couldn't get the desired results.

Dao

```
@RawQuery(observedEntities = [Plant::class])
fun getPlantsFromOrigin(query: SupportSQLiteQuery): LiveData<List<Plant>>
```

Repository

```
 fun getPlantsFromOrigin(origin: String, isFavorite: Boolean = false): LiveData<List<Plant>> {
    return plantDao.getPlantsFromOrigin(QueryUtils().getPlantsBasedOnOrigin(origin, isFavorite))
}
```

QueryUtils class - getPlantsBasedOnOrigin method

```
fun getPlantsBasedOnOrigin(origin: String, showOnlyFav: Boolean): SimpleSQLiteQuery {
    val queryBuilder = SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder
        .builder(TABLE_NAME)
        .selection(COL_ORIGIN, arrayOf(origin))
    if (showOnlyFav) {
        queryBuilder.selection(COL_FAVORITE, arrayOf("1"))
    }
    val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryBuilder.create().sql)
    Log.d("Generated SQL query", query.sql)
    return query
}
```

Comment: Based on the implementation of `SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder`, it looks like `COL_ORIGIN` would need to be `plantOrigin = ?`, and you would get `query` via `val query = queryBuilder.create()`. As it stands, you are dropping `arrayOf(origin)` by only extracting `sql` from the created query.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. So do you mean changing to this - .selection("$COL_ORIGIN = ?", arrayOf(origin))

Comment: Tried updating as suggested - `private const val COL_ORIGIN: String = "plantOrigin = ?"` but still this is the generated SQL that I am getting  -  
**SELECT  *  FROM plants WHERE plantOrigin = ?**

Comment: "still this is the generated SQL that I am getting" -- that would appear to be the correct SQL. Did you fix `query` as well, as I originally suggested? Right now, your `arrayOf(origin)` is pointless, because you are only using `queryBuilder` to generate SQL, rather than using it to generate the `SupportSQLiteQuery`.

Comment: Thanks a ton! It works. I changed the returning value to this - `return queryBuilder.create()` Now I am getting the required results. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder` is limited.

For `selection()`, the first parameter is the actual `WHERE` clause content, minus the `WHERE` keyword, and using `?` where any arguments should go. So, in your case, that would be `plantOrigin = ?`.

Then, if you use `selection()`, you need to use the query returned by `create()` completely. That contains both the generated SQL and the *second* parameter that you passed to `selection()`. In your case, you were just extracting the generated SQL, which means that you lost your plant origin value to use in place of the `?`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by CommonsWare helped me. Posting the solution code implemented with the help of the answer for reference. **Note**: If you want to return SupportSQLiteQuery use `queryBuilder.create()` but I wanted to return SimpleSQLiteQuery, so I used this -

`SimpleSQLiteQuery(queryBuilder.create().sql + " AND $COL_FAVORITE", arrayOf(origin, getFavoriteValue(showOnlyFav)))`

The reason why I hardcoded the COL_FAVORITE is because a **second `selection()` is overwriting the first one** but I wanted both. Would really appreciate it if anyone could provide a better solution rather than hardcoding it.

```
fun getPlantsBasedOnOrigin(origin: String, showOnlyFav: Boolean): SimpleSQLiteQuery {
    val queryBuilder = SupportSQLiteQueryBuilder
        .builder(TABLE_NAME)
        .selection(COL_ORIGIN, arrayOf(origin))
    val getFav = if (showOnlyFav) "1" else "0"
    val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery(
        queryBuilder.create().sql + " AND $COL_FAVORITE",
        arrayOf(origin, getFav)
    )
    return query
}
```

Don't forget to add "= ?" for your column names as mentioned by CommonsWare (refer the accepted answer)

```
private const val TABLE_NAME: String = "plants"
private const val COL_FAVORITE: String = "isFavorite = ?"
private const val COL_ORIGIN: String = "plantOrigin = ?"
```